# Idiomatic way to coerce xts object's data attribute to double

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I am downloading data from FRED with getSymbols. This creates an xts class object with the data attribute set to type integer for the series' that I am downloading.  I want these data to be of type/class double.
What is an idiomatic way of doing this?

```
  getSymbols("GDPMC1", src = 'FRED', auto.assign = TRUE)
  growthRate <-
      function (x) {
      stopifnot(length(x) > 1)
      (x[2:length(x)] - x[-length(x)] )/ x[-length(x)]
    }
 stopifnot(growthRate(c(2,3,4)) == c(0.5 , 1/3 ))
 realGDPGrowthRate <- growthRate(GDPMC1) ### zeros due to integer math
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the storage mode for `GDPMC1` to `"double"` via:

```
storage.mode(GDPMC1) <- "double"
```

But that won't solve your problem because the issue isn't integer arithmetic.  The issue is that xts/zoo align objects by index before performing *any* `Ops` methods (arithmetic, logical operations, etc), so your `growthRate` function will never work correctly on xts/zoo objects.

You can use quantmod's `Delt` function instead of writing your own.

```
realGDPGrowthRate <- Delt(GDPMC1)
```